# How to select 3rd parameter based on 1st and 2nd parameter from Jenkins Active choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to select FINAL parameter based on INITAL and MIDDLE parameters using Active choice parameter from Jenkins.

[image: Build With Parameters]

I tried the following steps.

1, Configured Active choice parameter as shown in the image with name INITAL.

[image: Active Choice Parameter]

2, Then added Active choices reactive parameter with name MIDDLE and Referenced parameters has INITAL.

[image: Active Choice Reactive Parameter]

3, Then again added another Active Choices Reactive parameter with name FINAL and Referenced parameters has INITAL and MIDDLE.

[image: Active Choice Reactive parameter]

How to make this FINAL parameter work based on INITAL and MIDDLE parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parameters `MIDDLE` and `FINAL`, should use `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` and specify `Referenced parameters`.

[image]